# MongoDB Local | Mongod --noauth | Issues

Tags: mongodb, configuration, installation, mean, mean-stack

I worked on a [MEAN](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/49262866911/the-mean-stack-mongodb-expressjs-angularjs-and) example quite a while back, but when I returned to testing something again, Mongo is giving me issues about authorization.

(All these commands are executed on Windows cmd - when run as an Administrator)

I have done the following :

- **mongod --noauth**    // to run mongo server
- **mongo --shell**         // started client

Now, in `mongo --shell`:

- **use admin**
- switched to db admin
- **show dbs**
- 2014 - 11 - 13 T13: 25: 36.747 - 0500 listDatabases failed: {
      "ok": 0,
      "errmsg": "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
      "code": 13
  }
  at src / mongo / shell / mongo.js: 47

I get the above error. I tried a lot of config changes (e.g.: run mongod with auth: `mongod --config=<filePath>`), deleted all my data from my local mongo instance, and started all over again.

I was wondering if I could get some help regarding this.

All I need to do is run Mongo without authentication, and be able to create collections etc, to play around with it.

I have looked into the Mongodb Documentation, but I find it confusing, I tried googling, but in vain because, all answers/references point to the [Mongo-docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/).

Honestly, I was having a hard time, figuring out the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I really can't believe this.

There was a separate instance of meanstack-service running in the background.
I investigated the processes in the services.msc, and Terminated it on sight.

I am quite glad that, now mongo seems to be working.